# Grouping not work

Tags: gridview, extjs4, grouping

im try group the rows of a grid at show moment, but i cant do.
This is my model:

```
Ext.define('Alnitak.model.PlatoArmado', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields:['IdMenuDiario','TipoPlatoTipoSubmenu','PlatoArmadoStr','Curso','Cantidad','Costo']
});
```

And the piece of code that define the grouping in mi grid:

```
var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',{
        groupHeaderTpl: 'Plato: {name} ({rows.length} Item{[values.rows.length > 1 ? "s" :     ""]})'
});

this.features = groupingFeature;
```

But the grid not show the groups. Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0):

Im sory !. The solution was very easy. I have define the "group field" in the store:

```
Ext.define('Alnitak.store.PlatosArmados', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Alnitak.model.PlatoArmado',
    autoLoad: false,
    **groupField: 'PlatoArmadoStr',**
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'mvc/stores/Local/PlatosArmados.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});
```